# code C# error getting ;expected

Tags: c#

code for Inserting into database

```
query = "INSERT INTO Question(Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer)"
   +    $"VALUES(\""{name}\",\""{answerList[0]}\",\"{answerList[1]}\",\""{answerList[2]}\",\"{answerList[3]}\",\"{name}\"};";
```

I am getting error in this line as "; expected":

```
   +    $"VALUES(\""{name}\",\""{answerList[0]}\",\"{answerList[1]}\",\""{answerList[2]}\",\"{answerList[3]}\",\"{name}\");";
```

Comment: 1. Which database product are you targeting?  2. Don't do SQL statements using string interpolation/concatenation. You are exposing yourself to SQL INJECTION attacks. Always use parametrized queries.

Comment: Even SO shows you have a syntax error...

Answer (score 4):

In three places, you have an unescaped second double quote, which *ends* the quoted string right there:

```
\""{name
```

and

```
\""{answerList[0]
```

and

```
\""{answerList[2]
```

Those break your C#, and if you escaped them, they'd break your SQL. So don't do that. Almost certainly, you should be using single quotes rather than double quotes as well (thanks Icarus):

```
query = "INSERT INTO Question(Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer)"
    +   $"VALUES('{name}','{answerList[0]}','{answerList[1]}','{answerList[2]}','{answerList[3]}','{name}'};";
```

**However**, that's very bad coding style. It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, it'll crash if one of your answers happens to have an apostrophe in it, and putting quoted or even just matched quotes in a string is highly error-prone, as you've discovered.

So start over and rewrite the code using parameters, which resolve all of these issues cleanly and simply:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

//  ...etc.

cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@answerList0", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
//  ...etc.

cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
cmd.Parameters["@answerList0"].Value = answerList[0];
//  ...etc.

query = "INSERT INTO Question(Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer)"
    +   "VALUES(@name,@answerList0,@answerList1,@answerList2,@answerList3,@name};";
```

Comment: Not only that, most databases won't take `"` as a string delimiter. It's likely `'`

Comment: @Icarus It sure is. Must be having a low IQ day! Thanks.

Comment: @AbhijeetChavan Remove the $, it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

try to build the string using like this:

```
$@"query = ""INSERT INTO Question(Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer)"" 
            ""VALUES(""{name}"",""{ answerList[0]}"",""{answerList[1]}"",\""{ 
answerList[2]}"",""{answerList[3]}"",""{name}""};"";";
```

never use a `+` when building strings, because it will evaluate both and then append them to a third instead of creating just 1 string.

Comment: did you use the $ before the @?
I just tried the code again, and it worked